# Does “Devour Intellect” reduce a wizard's spell save DC and Spell Attack bonus?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, wizard, ability-scores

Intellect Devourers have the **devour intellect** ability. This means that if you fail a save your intelligence is reduced by a certain amount. If a wizard with a 20 intelligence, at level 10, he would have a DC of 17 and a spell attack bonus of +9, if he fails the save, and his intelligence is reduced by 10, would this also reduce his DC to 12 and his attack bonus to +4?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### *Devour Intellect* only has an ability-score-reducing effect if the rolled “reduction“ equals or exceeds the targets intelligence score, in which case it drops to 0 INT. Otherwise, the INT score is unaffected.

The *Intellect Devourers* ability is worded as follows (emphasis mine):

> *Devour Intellect*. The intellect devourer targets one creature
>   it can see within 10 feet of it that has a brain. The target must
>   succeed on a DC 12 Intelligence saving throw against this
>   magic or take 11 (2d10) psychic damage. Also on a failure,
>   roll3d6: **If the total equals or exceeds the target's Intelligence
>   score, that score is reduced to 0**. The target is stunned until it
>   regains at least one point of Intelligence.

#### As we can see, *Devour Intellect* can only either reduce your intelligence score to 0, or not at all.

For example, if you have 16 INT and the *Intellect Devourer* rolls 15 on his 3d6, you **are not affected**, aside from the psychic damage.

Comment: I think a better heading would be something like "Yes, the wizard's stats would be reduced, but the Devour Intellect feature does not work the way your example indicates." Or something like that. Basically, the content of your post is indicating a "yes" to the question being asked; the side-note about the correct functionality of the D.I. ability doesn't make the answer be a "no." So I think the heading makes it look like your answer is wrong before reading the rest of it. (I strongly suspect that's why it has fewer votes.)

Comment: the question was if the targets spell save DC and attack modifier are reduced. While that technically can happen, it will never be relevant since you will either be not affected at all, or you can't do anything anyways. I'll edit later, but I don't have the time right now.

Comment: I completely misread this! Thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: @Bloodcinder A correct answer (for the specific example given in the question) is, in fact, "No, the Wizard's Intelligence is not reduced, because the *Devour Intellect* ability can not affect the Wizard." The *Devour Intellect* ability has no effect because every possible 3d6 roll is < 20. So, even if the Wizard fails their save, they *can't* have their Intelligence reduced by the *Devour Intellect* ability, because 18 < 20.

Comment: in the case that a wizard has more than 18 INT, you're correct. I tried to provide a more generic answer, though

Comment: @Makyen Check the title of the question.

Answer (score 18):

## Yes... If it actually worked that way.

Attack bonuses and save DCs are derived from attribute modifiers, and attribute modifiers are derived from attribute values. If the attribute goes down, the reduction chains through to the attack bonuses and DCS. The same thing would happen to a Fighter's attack rolls, and a Battlemaster's ability DCs, if his Strength or Dexterity were reduced.

## However...

Devour Intellect is all or nothing. If the roll isn't high enough to reduce the character to Intelligence 0, it does nothing to the character's Intelligence score at all.